# How do I fix when it says value assigned to it is never read in C#?

Tags: c#

Hi I'm new in programming in c#, I just want to know how to fix this issue because I can't increment the value of the points in the game that I am making...

```
using UnityEngine;
public class GameManager: MonoBehaviour
{
   private int point;
   public void IncreaseScore()
   {
       point++;
   }
}
```

[view image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jQ5kM.png)

Comment: This is not an error, but a warning. You assign a value but never use it. The warning goes away when you write the code using it.

Comment: Read the message and click the Show potential fixes.  In the real application however you would likely add a value to it and use.

Answer (score 2):

It's just a hint, so it doesn't stop you from run this code. However to fix, as information suggests you should read `point` property by for example assigning it to some value:

```cs
int someValue = point;
```

If you want this field to be obtainable by other classes in code, you can add `public` method for it and adding it will resolve your issue too:

```cs
using UnityEngine;
public class GameManager: MonoBehaviour
{
   private int point;

   public int GetScore() => point;
   public void IncreaseScore()
   {
       point++;
   }
}
```